# Bring up data from the database in the selected dropdown in laravel edit form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel and using ajax for make dropdown dependency. But, the dropdown can't show selected data that referenced database. 
How to do it? Should it using ajax too or any other way?

This my edit form code for dropdown part:

```
<!-- dropdown using ajax -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Pilih Produk :</label>
    <select name="id_produk" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
        <option value="">- Produk -</option>
        @foreach ($produks as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
@if ($errors -> any())
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors -> has('id_item') ? 'has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
@else
    <div class="form-group">
@endif
        <label for="title">Pilih Item :</label>
        <select name="id_item" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
            <option value="">- Item -</option>
        </select>
        @if ($errors -> has('id_item'))
        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors -> first('id_item') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

<script src="{{ asset('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="id_produk"]').on('change', function() {
            var produkid = $(this).val();
            if(produkid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'edit/ajax/'+produkid,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="id_item"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="id_item"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="id_item"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- end -->
```

And this the form display when i'm in edit form :
[image: edit form with dropdown dependency using ajax]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition for the selected value in option while you are on the edit page.

```
<select name="id_produk" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
    <option value="">- Produk -</option>
    @foreach ($produks as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" selected="{{$key == $editData->id_produk ? 'selelcted' : ''}}">{{ $value }}</option> // Here $editData is the collection by which you add the email and other option in the page
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, Thank you. But, how about another dropdown (Item dropdown)?

Comment: yeah, it does. Btw, about 'Produk' dropdown, it stil has trouble. Can you give the way please?

Comment: about $editData variable that take data from costumer data, there is no id_produk, i take id_item that get from second dropdown, so if i write $editData->item->id_item (its foreign) it still has error.

Comment: get the item collection using with after that use $editData->item->id

Comment: Also you can set something with Jquery as selected